# Преобразование к enum class

Tags: c++, c++11, enum

Законно ли преобразование значения типа `underlying type` к типу моего `enum class`? Т.е. можно ли делать так?

```
enum class A : size_t
{
   x = 0u,
   y = 1u,
};

// main 
static_cast<A>(0u);
```

Заметил интересную вещь, если пытаться преобразовывать значения, которые есть в перечислении (`0u` и `1u`), то в отладчике будут верные буквенные значения (`x` и `y`), а если пытаться преобразовать не присутствующее там число, но всё ещё типа `size_t`, то никакой ошибки компиляции нет, но в отладчике не показывается ни `x`, ни `y`, а просто это число, т.е. имеем сложнообнаружимую ошибку. Если преобразование законно, можно ли как-то контролировать правильность значений?

Comment: Кстати, `class` в вопросе совсем не обязателен. Неявное преобразование из целых в перечисление и для обычных `enum` не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хранение в enum-объекте представимых, но неименованных значений, не является "багом" или "неправильным значением" с точки зрения общей функциональности enum-типов. Если согласно логике вашего кода это - баг, то вам придется контролировать это самостоятельно. Собственно для того в таких ситуациях и требуется явный каст, чтобы привлечь ваше внимание к потенциальной проблеме.

Кстати, единственным "нелегальным" значением, которое можно "протащить" в любой enum-объект без явного каста является как раз таки `0`

```
enum class A : size_t
{
   x = 1u,
   y = 2u,
};

int main()
{
    A a = A();
}
```

Comment: C++17 обещает разрешить и через *direct-list-initialization* протащить нелегальное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно стандарту С++ (5.2.9 Static cast)

> 10 A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted
>   to an enumeration type. The value is unchanged if the original value
>   is within the range of the enumeration values (7.2). Otherwise, the
>   resulting value is unspecified (and might not be in that range). A
>   value of floating-point type can also be converted to an enumeration
>   type. The resulting value is the same as converting the original value
>   to the underlying type of the enumeration (4.9), and subsequently to
>   the enumeration type.

А также (7.2 Enumeration declarations)

> 5 Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other
>   types. Each enumeration also has an underlying type. The underlying
>   type can be explicitly specified using enum-base; if not explicitly
>   specified, the underlying type of a scoped enumeration type is int. In
>   these cases, the underlying type is said to be fixed.

и (там же)

> 7 For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the
>   enumeration are the values of the underlying type.

Следовательно любое значение базового фиксированного типа перечисление может быть явно преобразовано к типу перечисления, хотя в списке перечислелителей такого перечислителя не объявлено.

Когда же базовый целочисленный тип не фиксирован, то есть используется так называемое `unscoped enumeration` без указания базового типа, то если присваивается значение, используя явное преобразование, которые лежит вне заданного диапазона, то результат является не специфицированным (смотрите первую приведенную в ответе цитату из стандарта).

Comment: Разве в данном вопросе есть разница scoped/unscoped?

Comment: @alexolut Как следует из первой же приведенной цитаты из стандарта, есть большая разница.

Comment: @alexolut Для scoped enumeration любое значение базового типа может быть значением перечисления. А для unscoped enumeratiom без фиксированного базового типа присваиваемое значение может не попадать в диапазон, и тогда оно имеет неспецифицированное значение.

Comment: Так у ТС базовый тип как раз фиксирован, и даже про значения он говорит, что имеено из диапазона size_t.

Comment: @alexolut  И что? Я ответил на его вопрос, и указал, в каком случае может возникнуть проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказано в других ответах: каст, с точки зрения языка в данном случае вполне легален. Если же нужно проверять факт соответствия целочисленной переменной одной из констант `enum`, то самый простой способ - это дать константам значения из **непрерывного** диапазона и проверять попадание кастуемой целочисленной переменной в этот диапазон. Например, так:

```
enum class A : size_t
{
   x = 0u,
   min = x,
   y = 1u,
   z = 2u, 
   max = z
};

size_t s = ...;
if(A::min <= s && s <= A::max) { 
    // есть именованное значение для s
}
else {
    // для s именованного значения нет 
}
```

Задавать при этом дополнительные имена `max` и `min` вовсе не обязательно, можно использовать `x`, `z`. Просто так проверка будет очевиднее.